# HTTP/1.0 Requests

Tags: httprequest, hyperforce

We have received a notification that requests are reaching our salesforce.com Org using HTTP/1.0 and such requests are no longer supported.

I assume these requests are, most likely, coming from some other system or a user with a (very!) old web browser.

Is there any way to determine more details about where such HTTP requests are coming from? Information such as IP address and/or Username would help us identify where we need to make changes.

Comment: [Event Monitoring](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000339868&type=1) could help you to see requests and enhanced logs to salesforce. (This is a paid feature)

Comment: thanks @OleksandrBerehovskyi

Answer (score 1):

You can either [log a support case](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5) with details of your org or as suggested by OleksandrBerehovskyi you can try the [Event Monitoring feature](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000339868&type=1).

Alternatively, you can engage with your IT/Network team that can utilize readily available network monitoring tools to verify the version of HTTP for transactions generated by the application clients.

For any middleware product integrated to the Salesforce org, you can check the product's configuration settings to confirm it does not default to HTTP/1.0. You might have to consult documentation/support of the middleware product to determine how to find or update those configs.

Answer (score 1):

This was the tool we used when the disabling of older TLS protocols was announced:

- Go to `Setup | Login History`
- Create a new view to query for what you are looking for. You can include Source IP and UserName in the results

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce informed us of HTTP 1.0 connections in our org as well.  But, the information they provided also indicated that the connections are coming from the internal Community and Site guest users that are automatically created with Digital Experiences and Sites.

We have no idea why those users would be connecting to the org with HTTP 1.0, nor are we aware of any way to review or make a change to cause these connections to use HTTP 1.1.